# Prove that $c=\sqrt[x]{\Delta^x/\xi^x+1}\notin \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $c=\sqrt[x]{\Delta^x/\xi^x+1}\notin \mathbb{N}$ where $\Delta,\xi,x\in\mathbb{N}$ How can I prove this?

My try::

Assume $\Delta^x/\xi^x$ is an integer then: 
$\sqrt[x]{s^x+1}$ where $s$ is an integer. Assume $\sqrt[x]{s^x+1}$ is an integer then: $$\sqrt[x]{s^x+1}=a/b$$ where $a/b$ is irreducible.
$$s^x+1=a^x/b^x$$ But then I don't know.. so help me please

Comment: It's false, to begin with.

Comment: Why is it false to begin with?

Comment: Take $x=1$, and you get plenty of counterexamples. Maybe you want to exclude that case, i.e. insist $x\in \mathbb N, x > 1$?

Comment: x>2 ;-) $$$$$$$

Comment: Interesting choice of notation.

Comment: hahahahahhahahahha @NickStrehlke ;) I always write complicated notation for number theory  problems to make them look more fancy XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For intuition, take $x =3$. Then, if $c=\sqrt[3]{(\Delta / \xi)^3+1}$ is an integer, you need $(\Delta / \xi)^3+1 = c^3$ for some integer $c$. What are the possibilities? The first several are $c^3 = 1, 8, 27, 64, \dots$. So then $(\Delta / \xi)^3$ is a perfect cube that is also exactly one less than another perfect cube, i.e. $(\Delta / \xi)^3 \in \{0,7,26,63,\dots\}\cap\{1, 8, 27, 64, \dots\}$. Are there any such numbers? i.e. are there any pairs of perfect cubes that are only one apart?